# Proof linear map is linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I got a problem with the following exercise:

> Show that the subset
>
> $\{ f\colon M \rightarrow K\mid f(m) ≠ 0 \text{ for  finite number of } m \in M\}$
>
> is a subspace of $\operatorname{Map}(M,K)$

But since $f(m)$ is not $0$, I can not have the null vector, or am I missing something?

Comment: What are $M$ and $K$? Vector spaces? Is $\operatorname{Map}(M,K)$ the space of linear maps? If $M$ is not a vector space, is $K$ a field?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. 
The definitiion we got is that Map(M,K) is a K vector space.

Comment: You are missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how many $m\in M$ does the constant zero map assume nonzero values? For none of them, so it belongs to the subset.

If you have a map $f\colon M\to K$, define $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\{m\in M\mid f(m)\ne 0\}$. If $V$ is the subset you're given in the exercise, and $\mathbf{0}$ is the map $\mathbf{0}(m)=0$ (for all $m\in M$), then $\operatorname{supp}(\mathbf{0})=\emptyset$ which is finite.

Note that $\mathbf{0}$ is the null vector in $\operatorname{Map}(M,K)$.

For finishing the exercise, suppose $f,g\in V$ and $a,b\in K$; then prove that
$$
\operatorname{supp}(af+bg)\subseteq\operatorname{supp}(f)\cup\operatorname{supp}(g)
$$
and conclude that $af+bg\in V$.

Comment: Thannk you for the explanation.